# Book of 4 short stories, one about an afterlife, title begins with 'L'

Tags: story-identification

Book with 4 short stories in it, all pretty different, I'm pretty sure the title is a single word starting with L. A name maybe.

In one of the stories, a guy dies and ends up in an afterlife with lots of other people.

There's a canteen where they serve food that tastes horrible to start with, but you get used to it and eventually love the taste. They can also travel through a corridor, and the further forward you lean, the faster you travel through the corridor. It's all a bit surreal, sorry if it sounds very random!

One of the other stories is about a relationship, set in the 30s or 40s I think.

I read it 10 years ago, but I think it was older than that, written in the 50s or 60s maybe.

I had the paperback, it had a greyish or beige-ish cover, no colours. It did have a picture, but I can't remember what it was.

All the stories were the same author, they were all about a man, between 20-40 years old, but it didn't seem like they were really connected or about the SAME man, as they didn't follow directly on from one another and the events in each story weren't referenced in the others.

Comment: Did the other stories also have elements of science fiction or fantasy? What makes you think the book is as old as you say?

Comment: I'm not sure about the other 2 stories, but the story about a relationship didn't seem to have anything fantasy related, just the bit about the afterlife. I can't remember anything at all about the other 2 unfortunately! I think it's an older book because of the style of writing mainly, it just seemed like an older book, but it could have been more recent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend of my found it for me - it was Lanark: A Life in Four Books

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/161037.Lanark

Thanks for everyone's help!